# Is there a terminal widget library compatible with Python 3?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, widget, ncurses

I'm looking for a terminal UI library providing widgets like buttons, checkboxes and so on, that is compatible with python3.

I've tried:

- pycdk (pyrex does not work with python3, and porting it is a mess)
- urwid (does not work with python3, it has a port but not working well with new curses interface).

Does anyone know such a library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython supports Python 3, and I was able to make Cython accept the pyx file by changing all `__new__` to `__cinit__`.

Note that the examples still needs some porting to Python 3 at that point. I get "TypeError: expected bytes, str found" when trying to run the examples. Switching all the strings to bytes worked.

Possibly it would be better if the API accepted strings under Python 3 too, but that is definitely more work.